# Varnish include can't find file in the same directory

Tags: include, varnish, include-path, varnish-vcl

In my varnish default.vcl i have the following code:

```
include "vars.vcl";
```

When i try to start my varnish i get this error message:

```
Message from VCC-compiler:
Cannot read file 'vars.vcl': No such file or directory
('input' Line 6 Pos 9)
include "vars.vcl";
--------##########-

Running VCC-compiler failed, exited with 2

VCL compilation failed
```

The file 'vars.vcl' is in the directory /etc/varnish/ where also the default.vcl is stored. it is a symlink to the actual vars.vcl.

I have no idea why the include won't work, could it be that varnish can't work with symlinks?
Why can't it find the file?

Comment: I just tried reloading varnish with a include to a symlink-vcl on the same block device - that wasn't a problem at all. Maybe it wouldn't work if it's on another volume? Is the default.vcl also a symlink to somewhere else? For clarification please also try specifying the absolute path to the symlink-vcl (eg. /etc/varnish/vars.vcl)

Comment: double checked vars.vcl permissions?

Comment: the default vcl is not a symlink. the vars.vcl is in my user diretory, the path is `accountname\projects\...\vars.vcl`. the vars.vcl is readable by everyone

Comment: @Nafta just being pedantic, the varnish user has access to the dir all the way down to that file, right? and then, why separating paths with backslashes, is that windows?

Comment: I bumped into the same problem while changing configuration paths. I ended up adding the absolute path (/etc/varnish/file.vcl) and that worked.

Answer (score 5):

You have to pass the parameter `vcl_dir` to `varnishd`.  You can test it with:

```
varnishd -p vcl_dir=/path/to/vars.vcl -C -f default.vcl
```

Answer (score 2):

As @francisv mention you have to pass the directory location with -p(parameter)

`vcl_dir` is deprecated in 6.1.0 version so you have to use `vcl_path` instead

`varnishd -p vcl_path=/path/to/vars.vcl -C -f default.vcl`

**Just make sure path name should start from / other wise it won't work**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when upgrading from Varnish 6.5 to 6.6. It is solved with

```
include "./vars.vcl";
```